# Inequality between two limits

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $a_n \rightarrow a$, $b_n \rightarrow b$ and $ a < b$.
Is it true that there is $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for any $ m > N $, $a_m < b_m $?

I think it's trivial but couldn't prove it.

Comment: Recall the definition of limit and use it with $\epsilon>0$ such that $a+\epsilon\leq b-\epsilon$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

You may recast as

$$a_n-b_n\to a-b<0$$ and apply the $\delta/\epsilon$ definition of a limit to $a_n-b_n$.

---

Note that this approach assumes that the theorem on the limit of a sum is known.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: There exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that $a+\epsilon < b - \epsilon$.